# Javascript Позиционирование?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть рабочее пространство:

```
#joystick {
width: 726px;
height: 346px;
}
```

есть картинка *320x180*
её нужно перетаскивать в пространстве **joystick**
Позиционирование идет отцентра с координатами х и у цетр это (*0;0*)
когда её переместить в левый верхний угол то координаты должны быть: *-5;-5*
крайний верхний угол это *0.5;-0.5*
набросал следующий код: [jsfiddle.net/AsviS/gpkn3djf](http://jsfiddle.net/AsviS/gpkn3djf)
не понимаю как сделать **joystick** равен 1?
что бы координаты в центре были *0;0* а крайний верхний угол это *0.5;-0.5*

Comment: Не совсем понятно , что имеется ввиду. но почему бы просто не сделать вот так ? `var rel_left = (ui.position.left - parseInt($(this).data("startLeft")))/50;
        var rel_top = (ui.position.top - parseInt($(this).data("startTop")))/50;`

Comment: да да, разделить на 50, тоже пришёл к этому :) http://jsfiddle.net/gpkn3djf/3/